# Put a UIButton in tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I made a code for added a array of UIView in my TableView, but when I add them, it doesn't show them row by row while I made a loop for it to add each item in my TableView but it adds them one above the other, another solution?

my view controller :

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {

  private var myArray: [UIView] = []
  private var myTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

    myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    myTableView.dataSource = self
    myTableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)

    let DoneBut: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
    DoneBut.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    DoneBut.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let DoneBut2: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    DoneBut2.setTitle("Done2", for: .normal)
    DoneBut2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.addSubview(DoneBut)
    myArray.append(view1)

    let view2 = UIView()
    view2.addSubview(DoneBut2)
    myArray.append(view2)
}

}

extension mainViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
    "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    for array in myArray {
        cell.contentView.addSubview(array)
    }
    return cell
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
 section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
 }
}
extension mainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) {
    print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
    print("Value: \(myArray[indexPath.row])")
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add every subview to every row? A subview can only be in one parent view at any given time.

Comment: First: you are never constraining the view to the cell's content view. Second, the best way to handle this would be to make a custom cell and add the subviews to the cell in the cell class instead of in the parent of the tableview.

Comment: I'm making a tabbar and I want to do the same behavior as the more button of IOS which when you click on it make a tableview appear I think

Comment: @KaylaGalway i know, but i have to create my tabBar without a xib file

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Maybe post an image of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that each time the cellForRowAt function is asking for a cell, you are looping through ALL the views and adding them to each cell. Instead you should be indexing in it using the indexPath. See the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    // check if there is a view at the indexPath
    if indexPath.row < myArray.count {
        // there is a view, add it to the cells contentView
        cell.contentView.addSubview(myArray[indexPath.row])
    } else {
        print("no view at index")
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement here is unnecessary since the number of rows is based on `myArray`.